# Connection Refused when connecting to SMTP Server inside a Docker Container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, mailkit

I am trying to send an email from ASP.Net Core 3.1 using Mailkit.

It's working fine when I run the application through Visual Studio or a release build, however when I run the application using docker I get a `Connection Refused` error.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (111): Connection refused 159.122.219.43:465
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception source)
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at MailKit.Net.SocketUtils.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, IPEndPoint localEndPoint, Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

My docker-compose file looks like this

```
    server.api:
        image: server_api:latest
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "465:465"
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        restart: always
```

The server address is set to `smtp.sendgrid.net` which is being resolved successfully.

All other functions of the application work fine, I can access the api without issue.

Comment: Port 465 is SSL/TLS which is a secure connection.  So something in the security that is failing.  You can use a sniffer on any machine in the subnet to capture good results and bad results to see the differences.  You may need to deploy application if the Net versions are different to get latest security methods to work.  The working system may be using a cookie that is allowing it to work while non working doesn't have cookie.  I sometimes delete cookies in working app to see if it still runs without cookies.  A certificate may be missing or the port number could be blocked.

Comment: So based on what you mentioned, I disabled SSL and used port 587. This works in docker. So does this mean my container needs a certificate or something along those lines? A normal build of the app without Docker works with SSL on the same machine.

Comment: Some mail servers use 465 and other 587.  You have to check the mail server webpage to determine the parameters that are used.  Your docker compose is using 465 and not working, while using docker and 587 is working.